# My useNavigate doesn't work inside onClick function (react-router-dom) (localstorage)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, local-storage, react-router-dom

By default I receive in my localStorage an array " name" with an item at position [0]. In my handleExitChat function, I delete this item that I receive in my localStorage and direct the user to the main page '/' through the navigate that receives useNavigate(). When I submit the "name" item from my localStorage is deleted as I wanted, but I am not directed to the main page '/', I can only be directed to the main page when I put it in the url and not through of the button. I would like to know why navigate is being prevented in this function.

```
import * as C from './styles';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Chat = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleExitChat = async () => {
    const remove = await JSON.parse(localStorage.removeItem("name"))[0];
    navigate('/');
  }

  return (
    <C.Container>
       <C.RemoveChat>
         <button onClick={handleExitChat}>Logout</button>
       </C.RemoveChat>
    </C.Container>
  )
}

export default Chat;
```

erro

```
SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at handleExitChat (index.jsx:50:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
```

Comment: Are you saying that `navigate("/")` isn't navigating to the `"/"` path? Are there any errors in the console? Is the app navigating *anywhere*? Also, just FYI localStorage is synchronous.

Comment: Yes. There is no error in the console and I am not redirected to any page, I just stay on the same page but the localStorage item is deleted as I planned in the function

Comment: Is this component rendered inside any `form` element by any chance? Can you [edit] to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]?

Comment: One thing I didn't mention. But that '/' page is only allowed to enter if it doesn't have any items in localStorage. On my main page I have a useEffect that checks if there is any item in localStorage, and if so, it redirects to the page in question that I published here

Comment: `localStorge.removeItem` is a void return, are you ***sure*** there's no error thrown? I've tried that line of code and `JSON.parse(undefined)` throws an error since `undefined` isn't a valid JSON string to parse. I think we need to have a lot more context provided for what you are trying to do overall here. So you are saying that perhaps the navigation ***did*** work and that perhaps you are navigated back to the route rendering `Chat`?

Comment: I updated the question with the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

From what I can see there are a few issues specifically in this `handleExitChat` click handler.

1. `localStorage.removeItem` is a void return. See [return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem#return_value).
2. An error is thrown when attempting to JSON parse the undefined return value from removing the item. `undefined` isn't valid JSON. There's just simply nothing to parse.

The error is thrown and code execution is halted. The `navigate("/")` line is never reached.

## Solution

Just remove the item from storage and issue the navigation action. `localStorage` is synchronous, so there is nothing to `await` for.

```
const handleExitChat = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("name"));
  navigate('/');
};
```

And just in case this `Chat` component is ever rendered inside any `form` element you'll want to specify that the button ***is not*** a submit button. `button` elements are `type="submit"` by default if not specified.

```
<button type="button" onClick={handleExitChat}>
  Logout
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Something strange that is happening is that when directing to my main page, the screen does not appear anything and I have to refresh the page twice and come back.

Comment: @Routfin Are you referring to something rendered on the `"/"` route that you need to refresh the page to see correctly? Might be worth it as a follow up question as a new post. If you happen to create a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.